# Tangent; Parabola; Shifted; Normal; Shortes distance

Tags: conic-sections

I have a few questions on the topic of parabola. Here , they are : 
1. What is the correct/easiest way to find the equation of (i)a tangent (ii) a normal to/of any shifted/rotated parabola.?I know the equations of standard ones ($ y^2 = 4ax $and $x^2 =4 b y$)
2. What is the correct method to determine the shortest distance between two parabolas?( pre-requisite: Shortest distance lies along the common normal)
Explain the derivations, as well, please.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651369/finding-the-shortest-distance-between-two-parabolas   OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209893/minimum-distance-between-two-parabolas

Comment: Okay. But that answers one part only....